# Using Uniontypes and typeguards with class methods

Tags: typescript

I'm not don't think I understand how union types type guards are supposed to be used efficiently.  I am trying to use a union type on some of my class methods so that if they execute normally they return an expected value, but if they fail they return an custom notifier object.  Something like this:

consider this example:

```
class OpError {
    message : string;
    constructor(msg : string) {
        this.message = msg;
    }
}
class Foo {
    name: string;
}

class Bar {
    getFooName(myFoo : Foo) : string | OpError {
        if (!myFoo.name) {
            return new OpError("You forgot to name the Foo.")
        } else {
            return myFoo.name;
        }
    }
}

let myFoo = new Foo();
let myBar = new Bar();
let result = myBar.getFooName(myFoo);
if (typeof result === 'object') {
    console.log(result.message)
} else {
    console.log(result);
}
```

While it seems very useful and elegant syntax to say `: string | OpError {` the typeguard `typeof result === 'object') seems clumsy and has a magic string in it, and wouldn't work if the "normal" return value is also an object instead of primitive.

It seems like there must be a better way, but not sure what that might be.

Comment: What's the magic string, `"object"`?  That's just how JavaScript works, you check `typeof x` against a list of "magic" strings, including fun craziness like `typeof null === "object"` and `typeof (()=>{}) === "function"` and `typeof [] === "object"`.  The magic is inescapable for JS, and TS comes along for the ride.

Comment: On the other hand, if the "normal" return value is an object, how would you tell them apart at runtime with JavaScript?  You have to tell us that; there's no example in the question representing that concern.  I mean, what if there's a function that's *supposed* to return an `OpError`? Pragmatically you should figure out what runtime test you'd use to tell apart a normal result from an error result, and then we can tell you how to make TypeScript handle that.

Comment: That's exactly it jcalz.  Typescript kindly provides a very nice syntax either to return ether "Foo | Bar"  from a method but no obvious means to distinguish  between the two that I can find, other than once you determine its an object, calling object.valueOf.constructor.name, which has its own problems.  It seems an awfuly long way around for a language called "TypeScript" I was just thinking there was an easier way.  But maybe there isn't.

Comment: TypeScript is (with the exception of a few “warts” from the early days) essentially a fully erasable static type system on top of JavaScript.  It is not intended to provide runtime functionality that isn’t already part of JS (although it can downlevel like Babel).  So the way to solve any runtime issue should start with the JavaScript and then the TypeScript specific code can describe it and help coders do the right things.

Comment: So for an answer here I could make a suggestion for how to do it but there will obviously be edge cases

Comment: After looking at this again, I wonder if a simple [`instanceof` check](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#instanceof-narrowing) wouldn't work for you, like [this](//tsplay.dev/w6PGYm)?  The edge case there is that TypeScript has a structural type system and will mistake any object of the form `{message: string}` for a `OpError` like [this](//tsplay.dev/WPR8qN), and to avoid that you might add a `private` property to `OpError` to get nominal typing for it like [this](//tsplay.dev/w8EYrN).  If that works for your needs I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the JavaScript [`instanceof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) to check whether a value is an instance of a particular class (or one of its subclasses), and TypeScript [treats `instanceof` as a type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#instanceof-narrowing) the way you want:

```
if (result instanceof OpError) {
  console.log(result.message) // okay
} else {
  console.log(result); // okay
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDyAOBRATsg9s6BvAUNaAtgKZRgDmRAXNBAC7ICWAdmQNx7TBpN3ICuwWhgAUBCGWq9mZAJTYO+WgAsGEAHTFSFaAF5C49vgC+OEzlCQYAMTRp5+JmGIB+SfWnszFqNABCYTFx8ClobNAA5JyJRAE8w6jCZN0YWaAAfOCRUDHt8aAYAM2hhAEICONs1R2I5ILz8ZCJaPmQmaCYiAHdMlHRkYQAiAE00PmgCjDI0WmghdqjZpSJoMLUBmQVoI2giEAhluvrG5tbCCrQqqMM8k2NTHBwQJrOw3XauldthGXYnmfL-Jg9B1uoDvr9no0IHwQDM9ACAmoQmFIsRYol2DhCsUoTCZsw6GAmMAiGgighehhahwuDw0E81CA0GRhLjYRoSBByEQNttdvtcrSIPSiIzmaySHifvccEA)